# My user isn't logged out after the session expires using asp.net identity 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-identity-2

I have a MVC application using Identity 2 for authentication. After I log in, if I close the browser and then open the application again, there are 3 problems occurring.

1. The user isn't redirected to the login page
2. The session still contains some of the user details in the claim
3. The session is missing other custom information from the claim that is not part of the identity framework

I am using IIS to run the application on a Windows Server, but I can reproduce the issue on my local dev environment

Both the session in the cookie and on the server are set to expire after 1 minute while I am debugging the issue

[image]

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString(url.Action("LogIn","Auth")),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, User>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                },
                CookieName = "MyApplication"
            });
```

Comment: Are you sure it's a good idea to force your users to log out every minute even when they are active?

Comment: no it isn't it is just while I'm debugging the issue. I will set it to 30 mins when it's fixed

Comment: Why do you think the session expiring should cause the authentication to expire, they use separate cookies.

Comment: Even then, why? You should be using session storage - it is available throughout the session (while the user is active and hasn't left the website) and is deleted when the user is either idle or has left the website

Comment: I'm only using 1 cookie for the application. I don't need to store a lot of information about the user, just the roles, areas they have access to and is authenticated. The areas are added as claims to the cookie similar to how Identity handles multiple roles. I need to look into session storage but what I have works ok. I have fixed the issue with my expiry i will post the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that I never set the cookie to expire, adding the following 2 lines fixed the issue I was having

```
SlidingExpiration = true, 
ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString(url.Action("LogIn","Auth")),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
            // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, User>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
        },
        CookieName = "MyApplication", 
        SlidingExpiration = true, 
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)
    });
```